# Widevine CDM working on new Firefox profiles but not my main one

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, browser, drm

I'm trying to watch some sports, and the site they're on has DRM protection. For some reason, on my main Firefox profile, the Widevine CDM no longer works, despite it being enabled in settings, and all the required files existing inside the `gmp-widevinecdm` folder like they're supposed to.

If I create and use a new Firefox profile, it works fine - I can watch the DRM-protected videos fine.

I'm able to test whether or not Widevine is working via [this link](https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm).

On my main profile, it says:

[image]

On another newly-created profile on the same device:

[image]

Both have DRM content playing enabled in settings, and both have the same files under the `gmp-widevinecdm` in each profile folder.

I want to be able to use it on my main profile, as that's the one that has all my history, logins, extensions etc but I don't know why it won't work. Reinstalling and then using that profile again did not fix the issue either.

I also tried disabling all my extensions on that profile, in case any were interfering, that still didn't solve it.

What else can I try to resolve this issue?

I only started noticing this problem after I updated to Firefox 91. My current version is 91.0.2.

**Edit: More info**

Firefox is definitely recognising that Widevine is there, too. It's shown in `about:addons`:

[image]

It should be set to the latest version, too. It just doesn't seem to actually work when it comes to a DRM-protected, despite Firefox fully acknowledging its existence and that it's enabled.

[image]

Also here are the settings in `about:config` *proving* that I actually have it enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it!

It had to do with Firefox's EME (Encrypted Media Extensions) settings, which directly relate to how Widevine operates in the browser.

The following settings were (for some reason) set to `true` - setting them all to `false` resolved the issue, and I was able to watch DRM-protected content!

So in `about:config`, ensure that all the following settings are set to `false`:

```
media.eme.require-app-approval
media.eme.audio.blank
media.eme.video.blank
```

After doing so, it was finally recognised:

[image]