# “License request failed” with any site that uses DRM

Tags: windows, firefox, video, drm

I have been having problems with any site that uses DRM, for example
Spotify [1]. I visited this page [2] to test, and I get this response:

```
License request failed
DRM_FAILED_LICENSE_REQUEST
```

I am using Firefox 86 and Windows 10, and I have the "Play DRM-controlled
content" option selected. I also tried the `about:config` options here [3].

1. https://open.spotify.com/track/0tTk7qNzn8XGWIMak9e48Q
2. https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm
3. https://superuser.com/a/1673992

Comment: I might have accidentally typed in “Firfox” as “Firefox” but the overall edits were done to improve your question. The title is vague and the core formatting is using a citation format that is more appropriate for printed text and not the way Stack Exchange sites work. I am going to do one more rollback and fix my typos but if you want your question answered, you cannot have it so oddly formatted with such a vague title. [Original question format/text](https://superuser.com/revisions/1691402/1) for reference for others.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm

Comment: Many causes for this error - you'll really have to check them one by one as they are suggested here. (1) Missing/expired tokens, test by clearing out all Spotify cookies. (2) IPv6 incompatibility problem, test by disabling IPv6. (3) The license server may return a detailed error message that isn't displayed by the browser, see if Fiddler or similar can show more information.

Comment: What version of Firefox are we talking about? What version of Windows are we talking about? All information should be added to the question instead of a temporary comment

Comment: There is a new bounty, but I still didn't get an answer to my above comment. Have you tried it?

Comment: There is also 2, and especially 3.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a different browser?

Comment: It isn't site-specific, trying to get more information about the error. But it seems you're waiting for someone who already knows everything, rather than work with us toward a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Have it your own way. Let me know if you decide at least to execute my point (3).

Answer (score 3):

**DRM in Firefox** is delivered through a plugin by Google's [Widevine
Platform.](https://www.widevine.com) You can find it in `about:addons`, looking for the "Widevine
Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc.".

There's a **[bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1705138)** which has peen **patched only from V. 88
forwards**.  It causes Widevine to break on versions below that since the
moment Widevine has retired older versions of its Content Decryption Module:
see [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1331788). However there seems to be (or at least was) a
**workaround** which I've found in [this thread](https://discuss.getsol.us/d/6622-firefox-can-not-play-drm-protected-content-widevine/9), and which might still
work:

- in your profile folder, locate `\gmp-widevinecdm\4.10.2391.0\manifest.json`
  (the version of your widevine install might differ)
- edit the `manifest.json`, and at "x-cdm-codecs" substitute "vp09" with
  "vp9.0" (which is the old flag from earlier Widevine versions).

I'm not able to test the workaround right now, but it should be easy to do on
your install. If this doesn't work, there are good chances that you won't be
able to get DRM Content working in FF 86.

Please understand that DRM is [officially supported only in the latest 3
versions of Firefox](https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/articles/browser-drm-support). For Chrome, Google seems to [have been pushing this
practice](https://castlabs.com/news/widevine-cdm-browser-updating) for some time now, and they will continue to retire older versions
of Widevine, as they don't seem to have any interest in supporting older
platforms.